# how to get rotation deegrees with a-frame in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, aframe, webvr

I'm using A-frame to visualize a VR and I'm triyng to get the rotation degrees from the camera because i need to show to the viewers the angle of the view.
i saw this command:

```
Ent.object3D.rotation.set(
  THREE.Math.degToRad(15),
  THREE.Math.degToRad(30),
  THREE.Math.degToRad(90)
);
Ent.object3D.rotation.x += Math.PI;

Ent.el.getAttribute("rotation")
console.log(THREE)
```

but with react seems not possibile to get the `THREE` when i console.log it.

my component is this:

```
    import "aframe";
import { Entity, Scene } from "aframe-react";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import * as THREE from "three";
require("aframe");
require("aframe-video-controls");

const VRphoto = ({ BackgroundVR, config, rotation }) => {
  // With three.js
  const Ent = useRef(null)



  const A = (
    <Entity
      ref={Ent}
      primitive="a-sky"
      scale={{ x: -0.9 }}
      src={require(`../assets/images/vr/${BackgroundVR}`)}
      enabled
      camera
      look-controls
      rotation={rotation}
      // rotation="0 0 0"
    />
  );
Ent.object3D.rotation.set(
  THREE.Math.degToRad(15),
  THREE.Math.degToRad(30),
  THREE.Math.degToRad(90)
);
Ent.object3D.rotation.x += Math.PI;

Ent.el.getAttribute("rotation")
console.log(THREE)

return (
    <Scene loading-screen="dotsColor: #ef2d5e; backgroundColor: #000000;">
      {A}
    </Scene>
  );

};

export default VRphoto;
```

here are two link from the documentation of A-frame (vanilla, not eact)
[first link](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/rotation.html)
[second link](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/camera.html)

Comment: How about this one?
https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/rotation.html#getting-rotation

Comment: Hi @TasosBu, I've seen this too but unfortunately I can't figure out How to implement in React.. I'm quite new to the dev world.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(Ent.el.getAttribute("rotation"))`?

Comment: it gave me this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined"

Comment: How about this? `console.log(Ent.object3D.getAttribute("rotation"))`

Comment: nothing. I think there's something that i miss with the getAtttribute because is still undefines

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221830/discussion-between-s-zane-and-tasos-bu).

Comment: Ent.getAttribute("rotation") ?

Comment: @DiegoMarcos this isn't working.. i can't figure it out

Comment: Without a link to full runnable example it will be hard to help any further. https://glitch.com/~aframe is great